# Аналог "не приведи господи" але без бога

Tags: фразеологізми, стилістика

Чи є нейтральніший аналог фразеологізму "не приведи господи"/"не дай боже", який не має релігійного забарвлення/походження? Наприклад у подібній фразі:

"Вчися, бо, не дай боже, ще лишишся на другий рік" або "щоб, не дай боже, не лишитися на другий рік"

Російська має кілька фразеологізмів такі як "чего доброго" (інколи "чого доброго" зустрічається і в українських текстах, але не певен, що це не калька), "не ровён час", "мало ли что".

З українських спадає на думку лише "раптом".

Comment: Не зовсім як *не дай боже*, та все ж - *Щоб ти **бува** не лишився ...*

Comment: [Словники](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%87%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) знають *чого доброго*.

Answer (score 6):

Є декілька подібних висловів, які можна використовували у залежності до контексту:

#### {ще} не вистачало {тобі}

Вживається у зворотньому значенні «єдиний негаразд, який ще не трапився»

> *В Жежері поза плечі забігали мурашки. **Ще не вистачало**, щоб за наймита був вішальник!* — В. Речмедін

У даному випадку, *«навчайся, **бо ще тобі не вистачало** лишитися на другий рік»*.

#### не здумай

Фразеологізм [*не здумай*](http://sum.in.ua/s/zdumaty) використовується у значенні застереження від якоїсь дії і має яскраве емоційне забарвлення. Його можна розглядати як альтернативу до словосполучення *«не дай бог»* у сенсі *«не дай бог, ти зробиш це»*.

> ***Не здумайте** обирати його, бо так будете мучитися з ним, як я все життя від першого і до останнього дня мучусь* — Михайло Стельмах, II, 1962, 19

У даному випадку, *«**не здумай** прогулювати уроки, щоб не лишитися на другий рік»*.

Обидва наведені варіанти легко комбінуються:

> ***не здумай** прогулювати уроки, **бо ще тобі не вистачало** лишитися на другий рік*